# ImportError: No module named robobrowser

Tags: python-2.7

When i am trying run a python script with following code

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
```

I have got following error:

from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

ImportError: No module named robobrowser

Answer (score 7):

This usually happens when the library was not installed correctly, make sure you have installed it.

[Python robobrowser 0.5.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/robobrowser/0.5.3)

It's easy to install, go to your terminal and type `easy_install robobrowser` or if you have installed pip then you can also install by doing `pip install robobrowser`

Requirements: python >= 2.6